# Adding multiple locations with OR-Operator in job search

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I would like to be able to search jobs for multiple cities (possibly each with its own individual proximity range) at once. I can already include or exclude multiple tags/technologies, so why not locations?

I didn't find this option and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) doesn’t give any details on how to search for jobs. So if this already exists, it might be a good idea to add an explanation to it here.